# How to make a prototype function use the values in a constructor

Tags: javascript, canvas, pong

I am using the JavaScript canvas to make a pong-style game. I am attempting to use the values of the pong board's x and y grid values to create a prototype function for the ball to cause it to bounce off of the pong board whenever it touches. I have tried this a few different ways and I can't seem to get the ball to bounce off the pong board. I did not think that this aspect of the game's functionality would be the difficult part. I will provide snippets of the code below that I think are the problem:

```
var Pongboard = function() {
  this.x = 15;
  this.y = 15;
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  makeBall(this.x, this.y, 5);
}

var pongboardValues = Object.values(Pongboard);
var pongX = pongboardValues[0];
var pongY = pongboardValues[1];

Ball.prototype.checkPongCollision = function() {
  if (this.x < pongX && this.y < pongY) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
    this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  };
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working? Any hints would be greatly appreciated. If it helps, I will provide the full code below.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

//Create ball function
function makeBall (x, y, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

//Create pong board function
function makePong (x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 60);
}

//Ball construcor function
var Ball = function() {
  this.x = width;
  this.y = height/2;
  this.xSpeed = 6;
  this.ySpeed = Math.random()*8 - 2;
}

//Pong board constructor function
var Pongboard = function() {
  this.x = 15;
  this.y = 15;
}

//These are the values for the Pongboard object's location
var pongboardValues = Object.values(Pongboard);
var pongX = pongboardValues[0];
var pongY = pongboardValues[1];

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  makeBall(this.x, this.y, 5);
}

Ball.prototype.move = function() {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
  };
  if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
    this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  };
}

Ball.prototype.checkPongCollision = function() {
  if (this.x < pongX && this.y < pongY) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
    this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  };
}

Pongboard.prototype.draw = function() {
  makePong(this.x, this.y);
}

var keyNames = {
  38: "up",
  40: "down"
};

Pongboard.prototype.moveUpAndDown = function(direction) {
  if (direction==="up") {
    this.y = this.y += -1*10;
  };
  if (direction==="down") {
    this.y = this.y += 10;
  };
};


var ball = new Ball();
var pong = new Pongboard();

$("#start-button").click(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    pong.draw();
    ball.draw();
    ball.move();
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }, 30);
})

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var direction = keyNames[event.keyCode];
  pong.moveUpAndDown(direction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start-button">Start</button><br>
<canvas width=300 height=200 id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just had a very quick look. One thing you can do is remove the redundancy in `this.y = this.y += -1*10;`. You can just say `this.y += -1*10;`. Or since the numbers are not variables, `this.y += -10;`.

Comment: You have this -> `if (this.x < pongX && this.y < pongY) {`  These are 2 separate checks, you have combined them..   Make into 2 if statements..

Comment: P.S. If you're getting errors, say where and what they are. Also include where you think the problem(s) might be and what you have tried, so people don't have to spend a ton of time figuring it all out.

Comment: You're using `Object.values` on Pongboard, which is a function. The result is an empty array. Though there might be other problems here, the result is that `pongX` and `pongY` are undefined. Consider making Pongboard a regular object OR initialize it and just reference its properties using dot notation.

Comment: @Keith I think the checks need to be the same, since the ball is *supposed* to bounce off the pong board, not simply any x-axis location that is shared with the pong board.

Comment: Actually I just realized that you do create an instance of Pongboard, which you call `pong`. You *could* pass that to `Object.values` rather than `pong`, or you *could* just reference what you want by using `pong.x` and `pong.y`

Comment: @MichaelAlexander  It still doesn't make any sense,  when you say `pongBoard` is this meant to be the bat?.. If so, that condition is saying if the ball is both to the left of the bat, and at the same time above the bat, then bounce..

Answer (score 1):

Here I've got things working the way I think you want it.

You could extend this to make the ball bounce randomly on the Y axis too,..

I've commented out code that really wasn't doing anything too..

Also worth noting, you wasn't even calling checkPongCollision, so I've placed that in the timer.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

//Create ball function
function makeBall (x, y, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

//Create pong board function
function makePong (x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 60);
}

//Ball construcor function
var Ball = function() {
  this.x = width;
  this.y = height/2;
  this.xSpeed = 6;
  this.ySpeed = Math.random()*8 - 2;
}

//Pong board constructor function
var Pongboard = function() {
  this.x = 15;
  this.y = 15;
}

//These are the values for the Pongboard object's location
//not needed..
//var pongboardValues = Object.values(Pongboard);
//var pongX = pongboardValues[0];
//var pongY = pongboardValues[1];

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  makeBall(this.x, this.y, 5);
}

Ball.prototype.move = function() {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;

  if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
  };
  if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
    this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  };
}

Ball.prototype.checkPongCollision = function() {
  //if (this.x < pong.x && this.y < pong.y) {
  if (
    this.x >= pong.x && this.x < pong.x + 10 &&
    this.y >= pong.y && this.y < pong.y + 60) 
  { 
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
    //this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  };
}

Pongboard.prototype.draw = function() {
  makePong(this.x, this.y);
}

var keyNames = {
  38: "up",
  40: "down"
};

Pongboard.prototype.moveUpAndDown = function(direction) {
  if (direction==="up") {
    this.y = this.y += -1*10;
  };
  if (direction==="down") {
    this.y = this.y += 10;
  };
};


var ball = new Ball();
var pong = new Pongboard();

$("#start-button").click(function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
  setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    pong.draw();
    ball.draw();
    ball.move();
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ball.checkPongCollision();
  }, 30);
})

$("body").keydown(function(event) {
  var direction = keyNames[event.keyCode];
  pong.moveUpAndDown(direction);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="float:left" id="start-button">Start</button>
<canvas width=300 height=180 id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to depend on things that are available in the global scope.

`this.x >= pong.x && this.x < pong.x + 10 &&`

You should pass `pong` explicitly instead.

Comment: @IgnacioCatalina  Avoiding globals is certainly a good idea, but really not sure why your telling me..  :)

Comment: all I'm saying is you shouldn't be grabbing `pong` from global and instead pass it implicitly on creation of `ball` or whenever u need it as an argument to your method call.

Comment: @IgnacioCatalina  This is not my code, and this is not `codereview`,  I can see your new to SO,  so I'll explain.  When answering questions for OP's, you are not meant to restructure there code, otherwise it makes it harder for the OP to spot and understand the problem.  The global issue might not even be an issue here anyway if he was using modules or even placing inside an IIFE, but again this wouldn't help the OP understand were he went wrong.

Comment: Hi @Keith! I know it is not code review, but I don't see any issue recommending or calling out anti-patterns in comments. I didn't published it as an answer for a reason, hehe. I don't think you are understanding my concerns tho, It is not about using globals, but coupling two different types of object implicitly.

Comment: @IgnacioCatalina  `but I don't see any issue recommending or calling out anti-patterns in comments`  Nothing wrong at all, but like my first comment,  `why you telling me` ?..  I deliberately never changed the structure of the OP's code for a reason, like I just mentioned.

Comment: Well, you moved `pong` within `ball`. `this.x >= pong.x && this.x < pong.x`. They were already doing a similar thing tho.

Comment: @IgnacioCatalina And this was massively different to -> `if (this.x < pongX && this.y < pongY)`  for what reason?.  You saying a global `pongX` is less coupling than `pong.x`..?

Comment: @IgnacioCatalina  So what point are you trying to make again?.   I don't disagree that the code the OP has created is less than ideal, I like to keep things tightly coupled too.  Your initial comment was directed at me, and I'm still at a loss why that is.  You seem to imply that I have introduced some coding anti-pattern, when of course I never did.

Comment: Hey @Keith, I'm sorry if it sounded like I was calling it your fault. All I was doing is adding a comment for the original OP to read alongside your solution.